# show facebook product price in local currency

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have some Items in my game that can be bought.
I need to show the price in local currency BEFORE user click "buy".

It is easy, when the default price is in USD,
so that I call

FB.api('/me/?fields=currency')

and as an response I get

- user_currency
- usd_exchange_inverse

With that, local price is:

PRICE_IN_USD * usd_exchange_inverse.

But what if default price is in EURO?

It seems that I need to get exchange rate from EURO to LOCAL CURRENCY.

But how?

thanks

Comment: I don’t think FB offers that.